# how to use nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

i need some help to make nested ng-repeat.
I have the following code which which is not nested.Currently it prints all subject first and than it prints all student names.

However, I need to print students for each subject. 
How i can convert it in nested ng-repeat?

```
<tr>
    <td>Student</td>
    <td width="100px" ng-repeat="subject in subjects" colspan="3">{{subject.Name}}
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th width="296"></th>
    <th class="rotate-45" ng-repeat="student in studentNames">
        <div>
            <span>{{student}}</span>
        </div>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: We want to see your JSON data format and  display format

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example for nested ng-repeat. this might be helpful to you.happy coding

```
<body  ng-app="WeeklyApp" ng-controller="WeeklyController" >
        <div ng-repeat="week in myData">
           <div ng-repeat="day in week.days">
              {{day.dow}} - {{day.templateDay}}
              <b>Jobs:</b><br/> 
               <ul>
                 <li ng-repeat="job in day.jobs"> 
                   {{job.name}} 
                 </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
    var WeeklyApp = angular.module('WeeklyApp', []);

    WeeklyApp.controller('WeeklyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.myData = [{
                "number" : "2013-W45",
                "days" : [{
                        "dow" : "1",
                        "templateDay" : "Monday",
                        "jobs" : [{
                                "name" : "Wakeup",
                                "jobs" : [{
                                        "name" : "prepare breakfast",

                                    }
                                ]
                            }, {
                                "name" : "work 9-5",

                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "dow" : "2",
                        "templateDay" : "Tuesday",
                        "jobs" : [{
                                "name" : "Wakeup",
                                "jobs" : [{
                                        "name" : "prepare breakfast",

                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

    }]);
    </script>
```